# How to call a javascript function on more than two div elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to do a background change on few divs, but I don't know how.

here is the script:

```
<script>    
function hatterCsere()
{
   var x=document.getElementById("aktualis");
   x.style.backgroundColor="#666";
   x.style.color="#ffffff";
};

function hatterCserevisza(a)
{
   var y=document.getElementById("aktualis");
   y.style.backgroundColor="#CCC";
   y.style.color="#000000";     
};  
</script>
```

and here is the body:

```
<div class=aktualis id="aktualis" onMouseover="hatterCserevisza();" onMouseout="hatterCsere()">
   <p>Garabonciás Karácsony</p>
</div>
<div class=aktualis id="tanar">
   <p>Új Tanár Érkezett</p>
</div>
```

And I want to use the functions on the "tanar" div.

Comment: You should use jQuery; it makes this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: No; you should use CSS and the `:hover` selector.

Comment: Pass the div you want to change in as a parameter to your function instead of hardcoding the id `aktualis`.

Comment: @SLaks has the right idea, seems like something not fit for javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function parameters. Put parameter to specify element. Then you can do it cross-elemently.
Example:

```
function hatterCsere(element)
{
   var x=element;
   x.style.backgroundColor="#666";
   x.style.color="#ffffff";
};

function hatterCserevisza(element)
{
   var y=element;
   y.style.backgroundColor="#CCC";
   y.style.color="#000000";
};
```

You can call it like this:

```
     <div class=aktualis id="aktualis" onmouseover="hatterCserevisza(this);" onmouseout="hatterCsere(this)">
        <p>Garabonciás Karácsony</p>
    </div>
    <div class=aktualis id="tanar" onmouseover="hatterCserevisza(this);" onmouseout="hatterCsere(this)">
        <p>Új Tanár Érkezett</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do this in javascript, you should do this in CSS, like this:

```
.aktualis:hover{
   background-color:red; /*or whatever you want it to be */
}
```

however, if you need to use javascript,

If each div has the class name `aktualis', you can do this

```
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("aktualis");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    func_to_call(elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting *purely* for the CSS approach; the JavaScript is unnecessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the second (SLaks's) comment you'd got

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
     <style type='text/css'>
        div.bla { color:green;background-color:red; }
        div.bla:hover { color:red;background-color:green; }
     </style>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class='bla'>div 1</div>
        <div class='bla'>div 2</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: thanks, use full answer, 
but this is a homework for me. but now i see my homework title is:
"how to use javascript unsessery"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hatterCsere(id)
{

var x=document.getElementById(id);
x.style.backgroundColor="#666";
x.style.color="#ffffff";
}

function hatterCserevisza(id)
{

var y=document.getElementById(id);
y.style.backgroundColor="#CCC";
y.style.color="#000000";

}

<div class='aktualis' id="aktualis" onMouseover="hatterCserevisza(this.id);" onMouseout="hatterCsere(this.id)">
            <p>Garabonciás Karácsony</p>
        </div>
        <div class='aktualis' id="tanar" onMouseover="hatterCserevisza(this.id);" onMouseout="hatterCsere(this.id)">
            <p>Új Tanár Érkezett</p>
        </div>
```